# Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory

Tags: express

I'm working on my express app but keep getting the following error:
Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory...........
I installed path via npm and required it in my server.js and I'm still facing the same error.
How can I fix this issue? Thanks for your input.

server.js:

```js
  

    var express = require("express");
    var path = require('path');
    var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    var methodOverride = require('method-override');
    var PORT = process.env.PORT || 8081;

    var app = express();

    // serve static content for the app and set up body-parser
    app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
      extended: false
    }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

    // set up Handlebars
    var exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
    app.engine("handlebars", exphbs({
      defaultLayout: "main"
    }));

    // app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set("view engine", "handlebars");

    // Import routes and give the server access to them
    var routes = require("./controllers/routes.js");
    app.use('/',routes);

    // start the server listening
    app.listen(PORT, function() {
      console.log("App now listening at localhost:" + PORT);
    });
```

routes.js:

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// Import the model to use its database functions.
var burger = require('../models/burger.js');

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
 burger.all(function(burger_data){

   console.log(burger_data);
   res.render('index', {burger_data});

 });
  });

router.post('/burgers/create',function(req,res){
 burger.create(req.body.burger_name, function(result){
  res.redirect('/');
 });
});

router.put('/burgers/update',function(req,res){
 burger.update(req.body.burger_id, function(result){
  console.log(result);
  res.redirect('/');
 });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: You don't need to install the `path` package in order to use it. It's a built-in module available in NodeJS. Check https://nodejs.org/api/path.html for more info on that.

Comment: what structure does your project have? Make sure you have a folder `views` right next to your server.js as mentioned here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars#usage

Comment: My problem was solved the following way. I had a folder called view and inside of view, I had index.handlebars and main.handlebars. I simply had to move  index.handlebars from the layout folder to the view folder (one level up).